# Why is this script treating the files with the same names as the same files?

Tags: bash, cp, dirname

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

install_wm() {
    echo "$(dirname "$0")"
    cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd
    mkdir -p /root/.config && cd /root/.config &&
    git clone https://git.suckless.org/dwm && cd dwm && pwd &&
    diff "$(dirname "$0")/config.def.h" /root/.config/dwm
    cp -f "$(dirname "$0")/config.def.h" /root/.config/dwm &&
}

install_wm
```

When I run this script as `root` I get

```
.
/home/jim/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/ubuntu-server-LTS
Cloning into 'dwm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6504, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6504/6504), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3216/3216), done.
remote: Total 6504 (delta 3733), reused 5933 (delta 3287), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (6504/6504), 6.18 MiB | 8.86 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3733/3733), done.
/root/.config/dwm
cp: './config.def.h' and '/root/.config/dwm/config.def.h' are the same file
```

I run this script as `root`.
`$(dirname "$0")/config.def.h` is my config file that has different content, and is located in the same directory as the script,
than the one in the cloned repo. Why do I get from `cp` `'./config.def.h' and '/root/.config/dwm/config.def.h' are the same file` if the files only have the same names and not the content?
Also when I run `diff` on the two files manually, outside of the script, I get the output that shows the difference between them:

```
22,23c22,23
< static const char *tags[] = { "Brave", "ffplay", "Geany", "Terminal", "5", "6", "7", "8" };
< //https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dwm#Assigning_applications_to_window_tags
---
> static const char *tags[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
> 
30,34c30,31
<   { "brave-browser", NULL,  NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
<   { "ffplay",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 1,       0,           -1 },
<   { "geany",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 2,       0,           -1 },
<   { "lxterminal",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 3,       0,           -1 },
<   { "gnome-screenshot",  NULL,NULL,     1 << 4,       1,           -1 },
---
>   { "Gimp",     NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
>   { "Firefox",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 8,       0,           -1 },
61,63c58
< /* commands 
< https://youtu.be/wRh8HQ4ICwE
< */
---
> /* commands */
66,71c61
< static const char *termcmd[]  = { "lxterminal", NULL };
< static const char *downv[]  = { "amixer", "set", "Master", "3+", NULL };
< static const char *upv[]  = { "amixer", "set", "Master", "3-", NULL };
< static const char *mute[]  = { "amixer", "set", "Master", "toogle", NULL };
< 
< 
---
> static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };
```

whereas I don't get any output when `diff` is run from within my script. What is happening here?

Comment: `"$(dirname "$0")"` is not a reliable way to find the directory your script is in; see [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) Also, using `cd` in a script makes it more likely you'll get confused about what's happening where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With these lines:

```
mkdir -p /root/.config && cd /root/.config &&
git clone https://git.suckless.org/dwm && cd dwm && pwd &&
```

you're in `/root/.config/dwm/` by the time that `cp` command is executed.

And as the first line of the output shows, `"$(dirname "$0")"` is just `.`.

So at that point `cp ./something /root/.config/dwm/` is the same as `cp ./something ./`, or `cp /root/.config/dwm/something /root/.config/dwm/` ... you are copying a file to itself, which is what `cp` is complaining about.

You can make this a lot simpler by just telling `git` to clone to that path instead of changing directories:

```
mkdir -p /root/.config && git clone https://git.suckless.org/dwm /root/.config/dwm
```

Or even just:

```
git clone https://git.suckless.org/dwm /root/.config/dwm
```

As `git` will make the directories.